# Animate list in the middle of annotate arrow props

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am aiming to animate a `df` in the middle of an annotate function. I can get the arrow to animate and the first value of the `df` to appear but not animate with the updated coordinates. To do this I changed `label.set_text` to `(Number[i+1])` but this just displays the Number in the right place for the first frame. The position doesn't update as the new coordinates aren't called upon. I tried to run this code to update the coordinates but it doesn't display anything?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import random
from functools import partial
import pandas as pd

one_sample = partial(random.sample, range(100), 10)
a_data = [one_sample() for _ in range(1000)]
b_data = [one_sample() for _ in range(1000)]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 1)), columns=list('A'))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,6))
ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_ylim(0,100)

arrow = ax.annotate('', xy = (a_data[0][0], b_data[0][0]), xytext = (a_data[0][1],b_data[0][1]), arrowprops = {'arrowstyle': "<->", 'color':'black'}, ha = 'center')

Number = df[A']
label = plt.text(a_data[0][0], b_data[0][0], Number, fontsize = 8, ha = 'center')

def animate(i) :
    arrow_start = (a_data[0+i][0], b_data[0+i][0]) 
    arrow_end = (a_data[0+i][1], b_data[0+i][1])
    arrow.set_position(arrow_start)
    arrow.xy = arrow_end
    label.set_text(a_data[0+i][0], b_data[0+i][0])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,
                         interval = 500, blit = False)

plt.draw()
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48999869/animate-list-in-the-middle-of-annotate-arrow-props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you could use `plt.text` to display the label, you don't need it. `ax.annotate` can generate the label as well as the arrow. You can specify the label string as the first argument to `ax.annotate`,

```
arrow = ax.annotate(Number[0], xy=(a_data[0][0], b_data[0][0]), ...
```

and you can change the label by calling `arrow.set_text`:

```
arrow.set_text(Number[i])
```

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import random
from functools import partial
import pandas as pd

one_sample = partial(random.sample, range(100), 10)
a_data = [one_sample() for _ in range(1000)]
b_data = [one_sample() for _ in range(1000)]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 1)), columns=list('A'))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)

Number = df['A']
arrow = ax.annotate(Number[0], xy=(a_data[0][0], b_data[0][0]), 
                    xytext=(a_data[0][1], b_data[0][1]), 
                    arrowprops={'arrowstyle': "<->", 'color': 'black'}, ha='center')

def animate(i):
    arrow_start = (a_data[0 + i][0], b_data[0 + i][0])
    arrow_end = (a_data[0 + i][1], b_data[0 + i][1])
    arrow.set_position(arrow_start)
    arrow.xy = arrow_end
    arrow.set_text(Number[i])
    return [arrow]

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=500, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

To place the label in the middle of the arrow, I believe you would need to use `plt.text` (or a second call to `ax.annotate`). To move the label generated by `plt.text`, call `label.set_position`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import random
import math
from functools import partial
import pandas as pd

one_sample = partial(random.sample, range(100), 10)
a_data = [one_sample() for _ in range(1000)]
b_data = [one_sample() for _ in range(1000)]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(100, 1)), columns=list('A'))
Number = df['A']

data = np.stack([a_data, b_data], axis=2)
# a_data and b_data contain more data than we are actually using, 
# so let's crop `data` to make the following code simpler:
data = data[:, :2, :]
middle = data.mean(axis=1)
# find the direction perpendicular to the arrow
perp_dir = (data[:, 0] - data[:, 1]).astype('float')
perp_dir = np.array((-perp_dir[:, 1], perp_dir[:, 0]))
perp_dir /= np.sqrt((perp_dir**2).sum(axis=0))
perp_dir = perp_dir.T
# shift middle by a little bit in the perpendicular direction
offset = 3.0
middle += offset * perp_dir

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.set_xlim(0, 100)
ax.set_ylim(0, 100)

arrow = ax.annotate('', xy=data[0, 0], 
                    xytext=data[0, 1], 
                    arrowprops={'arrowstyle': "<->", 'color': 'black'}, 
                    ha='center')

label = plt.text(middle[0, 0], middle[0, 1], Number[0], fontsize = 8, 
                 ha = 'center')

def animate(i):
    arrow_start = data[i, 0]
    arrow_end = data[i, 1]
    arrow.set_position(arrow_start)
    arrow.xy = arrow_end
    label.set_text(Number[i])
    label.set_position(middle[i])
    return [arrow, label]

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=500, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you @unutbu

Comment: This may need to be another question @unutbu. But what if I wanted the number to be in the middle of the arrow. Would I need the `label = plt.text` to change the number coordinate to be `a_data[0][0], b_data[0][0] + a_data[0][1], b_data[0][1] / 2`.

Comment: Yes, in that case I think you would need `plt.text`. I've added an example showing how.